# Does the property of changing sign holds true for real sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that if a function $f:ℝ→ℝ$ has infinitely many zeros, then it changes its sign infinitely many times.

My **question** is: Does the same property holds true for real sequences $(u_{k})_{k≥1}$?

Comment: What about $f(x) = \cos x + 1$. It has infinitely many zeros, but no changes of sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property doesn't hold for either functions or sequences. Counterexamples are:

- For functions: $f(x) = \cos x + 1$
- For sequences: $u_n = \cos(n\pi) + 1$

In both cases, we have infinitely many zeros but no sign changes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $$u_{2n} = 0$$ 
$$u_{2n+1} = 1$$