# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to guaranty this property for sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, roots

In this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665493/does-the-property-of-changing-sign-holds-true-for-real-sequences) we know that if a function $f:ℝ→ℝ$ or a sequence has infinitely many zeros, then it is not necessary to changes its sign infinitely many times.

My **question** is: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to guaranty this property for sequences?.

Comment: A sequence has infinitely many zeros if and only if it has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: @fleablood: I am asking on the sign.

Comment: Okay, a sequence changes signs and infinitely many times if and only if it changes sings an infinite number of times...  (Um, as 0 is neither positive or negative isn't changing from non-zero to zero a change of signs?)

Comment: @fleablood: You write the case A is equivalent to the case A.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @fleablood: Does this solves the problem!

Comment: What problem?  A sequence can be any arbitrary sequence of elements.  You can choose it to have an infinite change of sign by changing the sign an infinite number of times or it can change signs a finite number of times by not having it change an infinite number of times.  There are no necessary or sufficient conditions other than it changing signs an infinite number of times.

Comment: @fleablood: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Take any sequence (or function) {a_n}.  This has no condition whatsoever.    Now take {|a_n|}.  This has no condition except that they are all non-negative.  Now arbitrarily choose changing the signs to negative and back to positive in a completely  arbitrary manner.  This changes signs an infinite number of times.  That's utterly no conditions (other than that they have infinite non-zero terms) for this.  It's kind of weird to think that there *would* be conditions.